# Open a Modal dialog Asynchronously in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Normally when you open a dialog using ShowModal, execution of the current thread halts until the dialog is closed. I want to display a Modal dialog, but continue execution on the current thread while the dialog is still open.

By "Modal" I simply mean that the user can not interact with any of the other forms of the application till the modal dialog is closed.

The Delphi ShowModal function provides a slightly different definition of "Modal" to the one I require:

> A modal form is one where the application can't continue to run until the form is closed.

Currently I have code like this:

```
dialog.Parent:=self;
dialog.Show;
// keep doing stuff...
```

This works, except I can still interact with the parent window (move it around, close it etc)

How do I show a form that stops the user from interacting with the parent window, without using ShowModal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the source code of Delphi\Source\VCL\Forms.pas and open implementation of ShowModal. Then learn how it works. I can't copy the source code here as it's an IP of CodeGear, but you can do this yourself easily and reuse parts of it's code.

Comment: This seems to have worked. I split ShowModal into two functions; ShowModalNonBlocking and CloseModalNonBlocking. I had to remove a few lines of code that would not compile. I am hoping there is a better solution but this is the best suggestion I have found so far.

Comment: I know that you can't post the code, but can you post hints, like "split at line X"?

Comment: @Mawg The "ShowModalNonBlocking" function ended with a call to "Show()". The "CloseModalNonBlocking" started by sending a Windows Message to Deactivate the dialog. Hope that helps?

Answer (score 6):

Even with a modal form open, the main thread still executes (otherwise the modal form could not repaint itself).

Modal forms however have their own event loop, preventing the original application event loop from executing.

They have to (just like Windows message boxes have to as well), as otherwise you could have an event sneak back into the main event loop creating yet another modal form or messagebox.

And that kind of negates the whole point of being modal: there can be only one modal form or messagebox per UI thread.

So you need to ask yourself this question:

`What actions in the main event loop does this modal form prevent from happening?`

Then move those actions into a separate thread.

--jeroen

Comment: I disagree. `ShowModal` works by disabling the other forms, showing the new form, and then running a message loop. I see no particular reason that the message loop *needs* to belong to `ShowModal`; it could be the one in `TApplication.Run` instead. There can certainly be multiple modal dialogs at once; simply show another form from within your modal form. Only one can be *active*, though; the others get disabled.

Comment: @Rob: interesting thought; when a modal window needs to be dealt with by the user before he/she can return to the parent app (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window), how could that parent app start a new subsequent modal window from another place than the first modal window?

Comment: The same way the app started the first modal window: Disable all active windows and show another window. Preferably, it would use the currently active window as the parent for the new one.

Comment: Isn't that the same as starting a new modal window from the current modal one, but without the risk that this new window is caused by something other than the current mode the user is in?

Answer (score 6):

Disable your parent form as long as your dialog is visible, this will prevent users from interacting it. You can also use [`DisableTaskWindows`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_DisableTaskWindows@HWnd.html) to disable all the forms and not just the parent form. It is not documented but you can see how it's used in `TCustomForm.ShowModal` in 'forms.pas'.